# datatable: process 2 frames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, py-datatable

```
data_df = pd.DataFrame({"AAA": [1, 2, 1, 3],
                        "BBB": [1, 1, 2, 2],
                        "CCC": [2, 1, 3, 1]})

lookup_df = pd.DataFrame({"key": [1,2,3], "value" : ["Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie"]})

data_dt = dt.Frame(data_df)
lookup_dt = dt.Frame(lookup_df)
```

I have these 2 datatables; one containing the data and another containing the lookup values.

I am trying to produce a result datatable with additional columns with lookups done.

For example:

```
AAA BBB CCC AAA_Category BBB_Category CCC_Category
1   1   2   Alpha        Alpha        Beta
```

I can do that by converting the lookup into a list of tuples and doing something like

```
for name, cond, value in conditions:
   data_dt[cond, f"{name}_category"] = value
```

Is there anyway to achieve this is in a more native vector "`datatable`" way.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a key on `lookup_dt`, and then join, each time renaming the target column to `key`, and then renaming back; use `dt.cbind` to bind the resulting list of frames

```
lookup_dt.key = "key"

dt.cbind(
    [data_dt[:,{"key":f[c]}][:,:, join(lookup_dt)][:, {c:f.key,c+"category":f.value}] for c in data_dt.names]
)
```

Output:

```
   |   AAA  AAAcategory    BBB  BBBcategory    CCC  CCCcategory
   | int64  str32        int64  str32        int64  str32      
-- + -----  -----------  -----  -----------  -----  -----------
 0 |     1  Alpha            1  Alpha            2  Beta       
 1 |     2  Beta             1  Alpha            1  Alpha      
 2 |     1  Alpha            2  Beta             3  Charlie    
 3 |     3  Charlie          2  Beta             1  Alpha      
[4 rows x 6 columns]
```

Comment: The lack of a reshape long / reshape wide capability is one of the key missing elements of `py-datatable`, in my opinion. A natural approach to your problem is to make the `data_dt` long, and do a single merge with the `lookup_dt`, and then if desired, reshape the result back to wide format.  This is done below, but is a workaround, given the lack of built-in reshape long / reshape wide:

```
# Set key
lookup_dt.key = "key"

# Reshape long and do a single join
long_dt = dt.rbind([data_dt[:,{"key":f[c], "cat":c}] for c in data_dt.names])[:,:,join(lookup_dt)]

# Reshape wide and rename to your desired column names
dt.cbind([long_dt[f.cat==c,{c:f.key,c+"category":f.value}] for c in data_dt.names])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid flipping from wide to long and back to wide for this particular scenario by taking advantage of the [replace](https://datatable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/frame/replace.html) function, before recombining. This should be more performant, although it does involve a couple of steps, and me ripping into some of your existing data:

```py
from datatable import dt, f
# ripping here
# if you can access a dictionary for your lookup
# which is a what a lookup is, then do so
key = [1,2,3]
value =  ["Alpha", "Beta", "Charlie"]
# the replace function is pretty strict
# you can only replace like type for type
# so string for string, int for int, ...
mapping = dict(zip(map(str, key), value))

# create another dataframe to munge
temp = data_dt.copy()
# convert to string, so that replace can work
temp = temp[:, dt.str32(f[:])] # you can also use as_type instead
# replace is an in place operation; no need for reassignment
temp.replace(mapping)
# change the column names :
temp.names = [f"{name}_category" for name in temp.names]
 
temp

   | AAA_category  BBB_category  CCC_category
   | str32         str32         str32
-- + ------------  ------------  ------------
 0 | Alpha         Alpha         Beta
 1 | Beta          Alpha         Alpha
 2 | Alpha         Beta          Charlie
 3 | Charlie       Beta          Alpha
[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Now, you can combine `data_dt` and `temp` with `dt.cbind`:

```py
dt.cbind([data_dt, temp])

   |   AAA    BBB    CCC  AAA_category  BBB_category  CCC_category
   | int64  int64  int64  str32         str32         str32
-- + -----  -----  -----  ------------  ------------  ------------
 0 |     1      1      2  Alpha         Alpha         Beta
 1 |     2      1      1  Beta          Alpha         Alpha
 2 |     1      2      3  Alpha         Beta          Charlie
 3 |     3      2      1  Charlie       Beta          Alpha
[4 rows x 6 columns]
```